# Source for Rebbe Shimon leaving the Mareh on Lag B'Omer

Tags: lag-ba-omer

The [Aruch HaShulchan writes in Siman 493 Sif 7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9102&st=&pgnum=120) that it is said on this day (Lag B'Omer) is when R' Shimon Bar Yochai was nistalek (passed away) and when he came out of the Mareh (cave.)

While the first point he makes of Lag B'Omer being the day R' Shimon passed away is of much discussion (See a very good article [here on the Seforim Blog from R' Eliezer Brodt](http://seforim.blogspot.co.il/2011/05/printing-mistake-and-mysterious-origins.html) that goes through the sources in this inyun and comes out that in the earlier sources there was a printing mistake and it seems to be the earliest makor is in the Sefer Chemdas Yamim.) I'm specifically asking in regards to the second point the Aruch HaShulchan makes that it was on this day (Lag B'Omer) that R' Shimon left the mareh. What is the earliest source for this (before the Aruch HaShulchan?)

(In the article from R' Eliezer Brodt he doesn't address this point and when I asked him personally he said he didn't have any sources for this.)

Comment: Interestingly, it's also on daf ל"ג of Shabbos.

Comment: Every source I have looked at points to the Aruch Hashulchan as the earliest source for this statement. (that doesn't mean there aren't more places to look)

Comment: @emmlinisrael anything after the Aruch HaShulchan I wouldn't really call a "source"

Comment: @Yehoshua How do you figure? If you mean a halakhic source, then why don't Rs Moshe Feinstein, Shlomo Zalman Aurbach, or Ovadia Yosef count? If you mean historical source for the Tannaim, then why does the Aruch haShulchan count?

Comment: @DoubleAA If any of those Gedolim would say R' Shimon came out of the mareh on Lag B'Omer I would still ask "from where do they know that?" ... Of course R' Ovadia would indeed sight all the sources. But unless they are saying chiddushim I don't see why their words should ever be taken without a source.

Comment: @Yehoshua Ahh I thought when you said "anything after the Aruch HaShulchan" you meant starting then and onwards, not anything after and somethings before too.

Comment: @SethJ What's the due diligence here?

Comment: "In the article from R' Eliezer Brodt he doesn't address this point and when I asked him personally he said he didn't have any sources for this."

Comment: @SethJ For sure! He happens to be someone that I regularly correspond with for many years so I figured he'd be the first person to go to

Comment: @Yehoshua, let me rephrase, any earlier source i looked at did not mention the Rashbi emerging from the cave on Lag B'Omer. and any later (after the Aruch Hashulchan) source i saw referred to the Aruch Hashulchan as the source. On the whole there are very few early sources that discuss R'Shimon bar Yochai and Lag B'Omer at all as mentioned in the article you quoted.

Answer (score -2):

See Halachically Speaking note 3 where the sources they bring refer to "Mesechtas Shabbos 33b, Bereishis Rabbah 79:6, Koheles Rabbah 10:8, Ben Pesach L’Shavuos page 302:6."

http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/230698/halachically-speaking-lag-bomer.html

Comment: Seems like a link only answer unless you tell us what those sources say.

Comment: All of those sources speak about leaving the mareh in general...however they don't say that it was on the the 33rd day of the omer

Comment: @Yehoshua Thank you for pointing that out, I noticed the same point but trust Halachically Speaking did their research before inserting that footnote---I'm looking into seeing if the meforshim on the daf explain it occurred on Lag Baomer.

Comment: @NJM "but trust Halachically Speaking did their research before inserting that footnote" ... That's probably the last thing to trust in our generation...But I understand why you did that.