# Which Rabbi asked for his funerals to be joyful?

Tags: death, funeral-burial-levaya

I think all is in the question. I think it's Rabbi Akiva but not sure...

I am also looking for sources saying funerals should be joyful.

Comment: I’ve heard this about R’ Shimon bar Yochai

Comment: Yes, thank you! "His yahrzeit is widely known as a Yom Hillula, a day of celebration. This is based on the original text of Shaar HaKavanot by Rabbi Chaim Vital, which refers to the day as Yom Simchato ("the day of his happiness"), rather than Yom SheMet ("the day that he died")" (Wikipedia)

Comment: If I can find the relevant Gemara, which i believe is in Yevamos, ill post it as an answer B”N.

Comment: @far22 but couldn't that reference to Yom Simchato just be a euphemism, as in Masechet S'machot?

Comment: I can't think, offhand, of any verse or source regarding joyful funerals. However, in *Kohelet* (Ecclesiastes), it says, "A good name is better than good oils and the day of death is better than the day of birth." Perhaps, others derived having a joyful funeral from this verse.

Comment: @DanF Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85682/9682